# How do I get a radio box that permits no selections?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a pair of radio buttons on top of a panel to function as a radio box, and it is mostly fine, but I need the user to have the option of leaving both of them unchecked (I wish the user to select zero or one of the options). They are both unchecked when the form is displayed, but after the user checks one of them, it is impossible to revert to the original state. I would expect clicking the selected radio box would clear it (I vaguely remember this from my X/Motif days) but that doesn't seem to happen.

How do I program the radio buttons to allow both of them the be unchecked? Or should I be using some other control for this purpose?

Comment: You could add a thrid radiobutton - and setting its text to "None" or something.

Comment: I would use two checkboxes here. It clearly conveys the idea that selecting nothing is an option. If the user tries to check the second checkbox, uncheck the first programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way to do what you're asking for. It is not that hard to do it our-self. Here's the sample code which shows how to do that.

C# version:

```
private void Initialize()
{
    radioButton1.AutoCheck = false;
    radioButton2.AutoCheck = false;

    radioButton1.Click += radioButton_Click;
    radioButton2.Click += radioButton_Click;
}

void radioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)sender;
    radio.Checked = !radio.Checked;
    if (!radio.Checked)
    {
        return;
    }

    var otherRadios = radio.Parent
                           .Controls
                           .OfType<RadioButton>()
                           .Where(r => r != radio);
    foreach (var r in otherRadios)
    {
        r.Checked = !radio.Checked;
    }
}
```

Vb.net version:(Converted using http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
Private Sub Initialize()
    radioButton1.AutoCheck = False
    radioButton2.AutoCheck = False

    AddHandler radioButton1.Click, AddressOf radioButton_Click
    AddHandler radioButton2.Click, AddressOf radioButton_Click
End Sub
Private Sub radioButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim radio As RadioButton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
    radio.Checked = Not radio.Checked
    If Not radio.Checked Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim otherRadios = radio.Parent.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().Where(Function(r) r <> radio)
    For Each r As var In otherRadios
        r.Checked = Not radio.Checked
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wrong language!  Question is tagged as VB!

Comment: Good job.  Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple if you think hatke.. Create your custom control

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class MyRadio
    Inherits RadioButton

    Private _permitted As Boolean = True
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)> _
    <Browsable(True)> _
    Public Property Permitted() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _permitted
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _permitted = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If _permitted Then MyBase.OnClick(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**HOW TO USE IT?**

```
myRadio1.Permitted = False 'Assigning it to false will not allow you to select it.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use checkboxes, they can be checked and unchecked.

If you really want to uncheck a radio button then use the code below:

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.MouseDown
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Dim thr As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf unticker)
        thr.Start()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub unticker()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    Do Until RadioButton1.Checked = False
        Invoke(Sub() RadioButton1.Checked = False)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Use this for each radiobutton individually

Comment: But there can be more than one checked with checkboxes, radio buttons doesn't allow this.

Comment: You'd have to add some conditioning code to disallow selection of both checkboxes at the same time.

Comment: Why do you need a button?  Why not just when the checkbox is ticked, if the other one is ticked, untick it?!

Comment: Yea, you can also do that

Comment: @Brian the code that I gave exactly does what you asked for

Comment: It might 'do the job', but it's not very elegant, and it's very convoluted for such a simple task.  I would refer @Brian to Sriram's answer.

Comment: What on earth `unticker` method does? Why do you need a new thread for this? And you suggest OP to use this crappy code?

Comment: haha you call this crappy? sir, I'm sorry if you lack so much knowledge xD , unticker method simply unitcks, run the code and see for yourself how precise and functional it is

Comment: `Do Until <flag>  ...  Invoke Sub to set <flag>  ...  Loop` is not precise, nor functional, nor useful.  It's a waste of CPU time if anything.